# How to install OpenCV on arch linux

Tags: python, opencv, installation, archlinux

I have tried installing opencv on arch using the aur package. It has successfully installed but when I try to import opencv2 in python, I get the following error

```
ImportError: libhdf5.so.100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Not just python , even when I tried running a c++ sample code using this, I got the same error. I have tried searching the net, found a few people who faced a similar issue but still I am unable to fix it.

I have installed Open CV version 3.2

Comment: I also tried installing the libhd5 package here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libhdf5/

Comment: Which OpenCV package did you install exactly? `opencv` is not an AUR package and provides version 3.

Comment: This one https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/opencv/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple packages with similar names but only one that works.

If you have not yet installed OpenCV, run:

```sh
pacman -S opencv
pacman -S python-opencv
```

Install [hdf5](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/hdf5/):

```sh
pacman -S hdf5
```

Note that [instructions](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/wiki/macOS-Linux:-Support-Libraries-for-OpenCV-4) for Sikuli, which depends on OpenCV, indicate that a symbolic link is required in `/usr/lib`. A system upgrade can break the link, which will have to be recreated to point to the most recent version of the OpenCV Java library:

```
# ls -la /usr/lib/libopencv_java*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2225952 Jul 18 02:48 /usr/lib/libopencv_java440.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Aug  5 22:42 /usr/lib/libopencv_java.so -> libopencv_java440.so
```

This can be accomplished using the `ln` command:

```sh
sudo su -
cd /usr/lib
rm libopencv_java.so
ln -s libopencv_java440.so libopencv_java.so
```

Comment: Actually, base-devel and opencv-samples are not necessary for compiling c++.

Comment: Note that `python-opencv` also needs to be installed due to the [recent splitting of the packages](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/commit/18c2a5cf0241bf4ff902df7e7bcae4afd2832ebc#diff-3e341d2d9c67be01819b25b25d5e53ea3cdf3a38d28846cda85a195eb9b7203a). Also, `-Syu` is unnecessary. `-S` is sufficient. Regarding "There are multiple packages with similar names but only one that works.", I only see `opencv` in the official repos, though there are (as usual) a bunch of variations in the AUR, including `opencv-cuda`.

Answer (score 6):

In version 4, in the default configuration, compiling `opencv`
requires `hdf5` and `vtk`, however it's not listed as a dependency
of `opencv`.

That is mentioned in the two bugs on archlinux page: [1](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59745), [2](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60901).

There are 2 possible workarounds:

1. `sudo pacman -S hdf5 vtk` (takes about `231.24 MiB` of memory)
2. If your program don't require `hdf5` and `vtk`, remove `-lopencv_hdf` and `-lopencv_viz` from `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc` (in case the program use `pkg-config`), or remove the 2 flags while compiling.

Warning: If you use workaround 2, update of `opencv` package will revert those changes. You may want to add them as a `NoUpgrade` entry in `pacman.conf` (read man page for details), but the file will no longer be updated and something else may break.

Answer (score 3):

for **opencv4**

```
sudo pacman -Sy opencv vtk hdf5
```

optionally, install Qt

```
sudo pacman -Sy qt5-base qtcreator qt5-doc gdb cmake
```

create a CMake project in QtCreator

paste the following

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(opencv LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(opencv main.cpp)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```